# executing sqlite querys - why I get TypeError?

Tags: python, sqlite

the code is :

```
with sqlite3.connect('example.db', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES) as conn:
    curr = conn.cursor()
    vals = ( surveyname , surveydesc , dictObj ,)
    curr.execute("INSERT INTO Surveys(Name, Desc, DictObject) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", vals)
```

the error I'm getting is :

```
 C:\Python26\html\xlsxhelper.py in register_survey(surveydict={u'q1': {'n': 3, 'nselect': 1, 'qn': 1, 're': {u'a': {'n': 3, 'text': u'\ud30c\ub791'}}, 'text': u'\uc88b\uc544\ud558\ub294 \uc0c9\uae54\uc740?', 'type': 0}, u'q2': {'n': 3, 'nselect': 2, 'qn': 2, 're': {u'a': {'n': 3, 'text': u'\ub625'}}, 'text': u'\uc88b\uc544\ud558\ub294 \uacfc\uc790\ub294? (2\uac1c\uc120\ud0dd)', 'type': 0}, u'q3': {'n': 1, 'nselect': 1, 'qn': 3, 're': {u'a': {'n': 1, 'type': 0}}, 'text': u'\ubd84\ub958', 'type': 1}, u'q4': {'n': 1, 'nselect': 1, 'qn': 4, 're': {u'a': {'n': 1, 'type': 1}}, 'text': u'\uccb4\ud06c', 'type': 1}, 'qn': 4}, surveyname='qwe', surveyinfo='Survey Description\r\nqwe')
  101         with sqlite3.connect('example.db', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES) as conn:
  102             curr = conn.cursor()
  103             vals = (surveyname , surveydesc , dictObj) <= somehow this line is highlighted
  104             curr.execute("INSERT INTO Surveys(Name, Desc, DictObject) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", vals)
  105             conn.commit()                       
vals undefined, surveyname = 'qwe', surveydesc undefined, dictObj = 'eJwLVg8uLSpLrVRwSS1OLsosKMnMz4spiskrLE9V5yow5NIDANCTC5w=\n'
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: function takes at most 2 arguments (4 given) 
      args = ('function takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)',) 
      message = 'function takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)'
```

what does function takes at most 2 arguments mean? what function am I calling here? `curr.execute` takes 2 arguments : actual query and parameters. why is line 103 getting highlighted? that is a simple assignment of a tuple.

surveyname and surveyname are simple strings. dictObj is a dictionary pickled and compressed into a string. So, three strings are inserted to a row which has text/text/blob columns. I can't find what is wrong here..

Comment: What development environment are you using? That is not a regular python traceback; a lot of information has been added to it. I suspect that your dev environment may be the ultimate cause of the mismatch between source and actually executed bytecode here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that is a cgitb traceback. I think it has to do with modules not being compiled after the script has been updated; I manually delete *.pyo files however can't see where *.pyc files are.

Comment: Ah, interesting, never used cgitb myself. No idea how your CGI is being run then either. The fact that `vals` is undefined and that the exception and line are not matching does show a mismatch between what python is running and what the `.py` file contains when the error occurs. Is there an HTTP server or similar that needs restarting?

Comment: @MartijnPieters the code is run as : IIS -> PyISAPIe -> PyIASPIe WSGI module -> my code

Comment: Right, and the WSGI module caches your code; it is *not* reloaded when you change the source. You need to restart IIS or otherwise reload the WSGI module.

Comment: According to [this page](https://bitbucket.org/rsyring/isapi-wsgi) you need to use `iisreset` to stop and start IIS to reload your WSGI environment properly. I quote: *If you make a change to your python code and things do not seem to work, try restarting IIS. Starting and stopping the website within MMC is not enough. I recommend the command line iisreset to stop and start IIS. This will clear the environment and cleanly reload any changes to your code.*

Answer (score 0):

Python is not running that code; it's running a *previous* version of your python file that had a different line in it; at a guess that was:

```
curr.execute("INSERT INTO Surveys(Name, Desc, DictObject) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", surveyname , surveydesc , dictObj)
```

A python traceback has to read the source code again to show you the line that caused the error, but if you changed the source in the meantime it'll not match the actual bytecode that caused the error.

Restart your python script (or whatever runs your script, like a WSGI module in a HTTP server); if the problem persists, delete all `*.pyc` files, and make sure that when you save a change to your script, it's modification date is updated.